# Databricks - Spark streaming auto-loader wildcard

Tags: databricks, wildcard, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-autoloader

Need som help with an issue loading a subdirectory from S3 bucket using auto-loader. For example:

S3://path1/path2/databases*/paths/

In databases there are various versions of databases. For example database_v1, database_v2, database_v3 ...

```
autoloader_options = {
"cloudFiles.format": "parquet",
"cloudFiles.schemaLocation":f'{defs["schema_checkpoint_name"]}'
}


# AutoLoader
readstream_dataframe_autoloader = (
    spark.readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .options(**autoloader_options)
    .load(
     'S3://path1/path2/databases*/paths/ '
        )
)
```

Already tried "cloudFiles.recursiveFileLookup": "true"

Also tried to pass a list but Databricks does not supports directory list.

somewhat doing this without autoloader, it works.

```
df_transaction = (
   spark.readStream
   .format("parquet")
   .option("rowsPerSecond", 100)
   .schema(<someschema>)
   .load("S3://path1/path2/databases*/paths/") 
   )
```

Comment: Hmmm, just tested it - it works. What error do you get?

Comment: https://kb.databricks.com/scala/pattern-match-files-in-path

Comment: Inferschema seems like it takes the asterisk as a director and stops at:  S3://path1/path2/. There is no error thrown but the code never ends because it takes all the landing zone.  when I just want to access to a single file: 

Listing s3://path/data to choose a sample of files for schema inference
Where I need: s3://path/data/database*/path/bank_fee

Comment: Single directory* not file. In this case bank_fee and all inside of it